# How many ways can the floor be tiled?

Tags: mathematics

A space measuring 3 by 10 is to be tiled. Tiles are square and come in sizes 1 by 1, 2 by 2 and 3 by 3. How many ways can the floor be tiled?

Comment: I have a solution but I'll refrain from posting it until the weekend per http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/2808/4508

Comment: Maybe you should wait a couple of weeks before answering. It is Chinese New Year and a lot of long-lasting celebration

Comment: This sounds like a generic combinatorics problem. I imagine it can be solved by a recursion, possibly expressed as a generating function. Is there a nice solution we should be looking for?

Comment: The key with puzzles is that when you look at them and they are good you sometimes think of them in terms of a complicated problem - they become a puzzle when you need to find a unique way to solve them without employing complicated math - here it seems to be the same challenge, I assume that the creator found some way not obvious to solve the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Consider a 3 by n space to be tiled, with the dimension of length 3 vertical. The largest piece touching the left side must either be 3x3, 2x2, or 1x1.

If it is 3x3, removing it leaves a 3 by n-3 space.

If it is 2x2, there are two places it can be (up or down), and it must be accompanied by two 1x1 pieces because those are the only ones which can fit in the space. Removing all of these leaves a 3 by n-2 space.

If it is 1x1, then the left column is 3 1x1 pieces, and removing it leaves a 3 by n-1 space.

So if we let f(n) be the number of ways to tile the 3 by n space, then for n>0 we have f(n)=f(n-3)+2f(n-2)+f(n-3) (define f(-2)=f(-1)=0, f(0)=1).

The only thing left is to calculate f(10), which can be done by working up using the recursion. f(1)=1, f(2)=3, f(3)=6, f(4)=13, f(5)=28, f(6)=60, f(7)=129, f(8)=277, f(9)=595, and f(10)=1278. So 1278 is the answer.

Comment: You have f(n-3) in there twice instead of also f(n-1)